# Creating sequelize migation manually

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize and have been using it for months without the sequelize cli. I'm almost ready to launch, but when I realize I can't change the database without a migration, I stack. Please help me. I don't want to reconfigure the database and recreate the model.What if I use alter: true in production?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sync` (either with `alter: true` or not) on a production environment is totally a bad idea, Sequelize says it in its documentation as well.

To keep the existing DB structure and add an ability to modify the DB using migration files you need to remove `sync` call and do the following steps:

**Preparation:**

1. Configure Sequelize CLI to use a table to store a list of applied migrations
2. Run `sequelize db:migrate` on all DBs.
3. Make sure you got the empty migration table indicated in p.1
4. Unload the actual whole DB structure from any DB (let's assume they are identical in terms of a structure) as an SQL script.
5. Create the initial migration by using Sequelize CLI and add a piece of code to apply the script from p.4 inside it.
6. Insert a new record with the name of the created migration file (including the file extension) into the migration table manually in all DBs

**Testing:**

1. Prepare a test DB including the migration table with the initial migration record
2. Run `sequelize db:migrate` on the DB
3. Make sure the previous command does not apply any migrations.
4. Create a new test migration that should add/modify something in the DB
5. Run `sequelize db:migrate` on the DB
6. Make sure the previous command applied the new migration.
7. Delete the migration file and the DB

Comment: Thanks. I will test your solution. What about this one? `Modal.sync({alter: {drop: false,}});`

Comment: I recommend to use `sync` only on a development or test DB just for some Proof-of-Concept and not for a real DB and especially not for a production DB.

Comment: I get this error `ERROR: The dialect [object Object] is not supported. Supported dialects: mssql, mariadb, mysql, oracle, postgres, db2 and sqlite.` when i run `sequelize db:migrate` can you please help me

Comment: Show your DB config in the post, it seems you didn't indicate `dialect` properly

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75648309/error-the-dialect-object-object-is-not-supported-supported-dialects-mssql) I asked it today on stackoverflow