# ERROR: The dialect [object Object] is not supported. Supported dialects: mssql, mariadb, mysql, oracle, postgres, db2 and sqlite

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration

When I try to run sequelize db:migrate In the cli, I get this error;

```
ERROR: The dialect [object Object] is not supported. Supported dialects: mssql, mariadb, mysql, oracle, postgres, db2 and sqlite.
```

config.js

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'migration', 'root', null, {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        logging: false,
    }
);
```

I use `.sequelizerc` file to point the path to the file.Please help me. I know there are questions like this, but none of them have a clear explanation.

Comment: Please show the whole `.sequelizerc` content and the whole `config.js`

Comment: .sequelizerc `module.exports = {
    'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js'),
    'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
}; `

Comment: It's better to show both as formatted text blocks in the post

Comment: hey can you give me an alternative way without migration please

Comment: Once again `sync` is not for production environment! There is no other ways to keep the Db structure up to date apart from `sync` and `migrations`